# throwing new exception doesn't show anything in post man response

Tags: scala, exception, playframework

I'm developing a play scala application, i'm throwing an exception once the locale is not found throw filter, my problem is the message is not getting displayed in postman once an exception occurred i have no idea why, here is my code

```
class LocaleFilter @Inject()(implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {

  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
    val localeIndex = requestHeader.path.indexOf("v1") + 3
    val localeRequest = requestHeader.path.replace("//", "/").split("/")(3);
    if (!isExistingLocale(localeRequest)) {
      throw new CustomException("Locale not found")
    }
    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>

      val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      val requestTime = endTime - startTime

      Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri} took ${requestTime}ms and returned ${result.header.status}")

      result.withHeaders("Request-Time" -> requestTime.toString)
    }


  }

  def isExistingLocale(locale: String): Boolean = {

    val properties = ConnectionLoader.getConnectionProperties(locale);
    return null != properties;

  }

  case class CustomException(private val message: String = "",
                             private val cause: Throwable = None.orNull)
    extends Exception(message, cause)

}
```

and here is the postman result[image]

the post man result should be locale not found which is missed and the code is 500 should be fine

Comment: Actually you don’t need an exception (which is a side effect). You can just replace ˋthrow new CustomException(« Locale not found »)ˋ by ˋreturn InternalServerError(« Locale not found »)`

Comment: @Donmyar by what ?

Comment: I have edited the comment

Comment: it connot be resolved :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue you can use trait `Results` (I don't know if it is the best solution). Here is an exemple of filter :

```
import akka.stream.Materializer
import javax.inject._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

@Singleton
class ExampleFilter @Inject()(
    implicit override val mat: Materializer,
    exec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter with Results { // added `with Results` to be able to use `InternalServerError`

  override def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    // ...

    if(/* ... */){
        return Future.successful(InternalServerError("Locale not found"))
    }

    // ...

    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
       // ...
    }
  }

}
```

The curl returns a `500` with the right message :

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:9000
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:9000/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Length: 16
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Date: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 13:31:43 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Locale not found%
```

Comment: thank you for your response, internalServerError is not resolved :/ does it need any import ?

Comment: Did you added `with Results` ? (I just edited to add missing imports)